# Convert filename-date to datetime

Tags: javascript, php

I have files with filenames like `filename-0001#18-02-2012^16.04.43.JPG`.
I have split the file names to extract the date/time part. 
Now I want convert that part (e.g. `18/02/2012 - 16:04:43`) to something like `1482581580` so I can sort by date/time.

This is my code:

```
$convert =

$string = $withoutExt;
$find = array('/_/', '/\./', '/-/');
$replace = array('/', ':', '/');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
$split   = preg_split('/\/00|\^|#/', $result);
//print_r($split);
$korrasNimi = $split[0];

$date = $split[2];
$time = $split[3];

<td data-order="<?php echo $convert ?>">
    <span class="text-center">
       <?php echo $kuupaev; echo ' - ' echo $kellaaeg; ?>
    </span>
</td>
```

How can I get the numerical representation of the date?

Comment: And what is not working here?

Comment: try this : `$datetime = strtotime(date('18/02/2012 16:04:43');`

Comment: @u_mulder I dont know how to convert it to datetime, so I can sort by datetime

Comment: Date and time processing is always difficult, countless lines of code have been written to deal with it, and are constantly being written. Consider using a library like momentjs which has many features for parsing, displaying and manipulating. Storing date/times as UTC strings is a good idea, because they are human readable and also sortable without going to a numeric format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string like `18/02/2012 - 16:04:43` then you can [create `datetime` object from a certain format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y - H:i:s', '18/02/2012 - 16:04:43');
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
echo $timestamp;
```